# Minimizing total number of comparisons on a set of numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, optimization, triangles

Suppose $S=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{50}\}$ is a set of distinct integers that $1\le a_i\le200$ $(\forall i$ $1\le i\le 50)$

Let $D\subset S^3$ be the subset that doesn't contain any repetitive element in 3-tuples. There is a function $F:D\to\{0,1\}$ that each time we call $F(x,y,z)$ it returns $1$ iff $x+y\gt z$ and o.w it returns $0$.

(We don't know the values for $a_i$s, they're just labels. So we can't sort them for instance)

What is the minimum number of times of calling $F$ so we can be sure either $F$ is a constant function equaling $1$ or there's an input for which $F$ gives us $0$?

Comment: A trivial upper bound would of course be $\binom{50}{3}$. I had one idea which is a little bit better: We can do it in $\binom{50}{2} - 50$ comparisons by choosing $x, z \in S, x \neq z$ in every turn and checking $F(x, x, z)$. This works because if there are $x, y, z \in S$ such that $F(x, y, z) = 0$ then either for $w = x$ or for $w = y$ we have $F(w, w, z) = 0$.

Comment: @araomisThank you your comment made me do an edit to clarify we can't input a tuple with repetitive element unfortunately!

Comment: Ok. For the sake of completeness/correctness: Actually I made (at least) two mistakes above: The "trivial" upper bound is wrong: I guess it should be just $50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48 / 2$ instead of $50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48 / 6$ because we have to pick three numbers and then call F three times (each time another number is on the RHS). Also the second bound I gave is incorrect: I guess this one should be $50 \cdot 49$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the worst case it takes $3\binom{50}{3}$ invocations. This worst case is when the sum of the two smallest elements equals the largest element. Then there is only one invocation that fails, and the ones that succeed don't give you any information to help you find it.

Comment: Oh nice! Actually an easy proof would be to consider the following two sets: $S_1 = \{ 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, ... , 11, 20\}, S_2 = \{10, 11, 11, 11, ..., 20\}$. It is clear that for $S_1$ $F$ can be $0$. For $S_2$ on the other hand that is not possible but there is only exactly one test which will tell you this, namely $F(10, 10, 20)$. Doing $3\binom{50}{3} - 1$ tests can give you all $1$'s in both cases. This proves that those tests do not give you any information about the last test.

Comment: But given the extremely limited range of values, it is not possible for so few triples to fail to satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: @ErickWong, ${99,101,153,154,155,\ldots,200}$

Comment: Oh, you mean this problem is about finding a set which is *not* the sides of a triangle?  I must have assumed it was the more interesting version :)

Comment: I will be happy to remove my downvote, but can no longer do so unless the answer is edited.